# Attribute data-ls not allowed on element svg at this point. how to rectify it

Tags: html, svg, w3c, w3c-validation, svg-animate

While checking my site with w3cvalidator

it shows the this error **Attribute data-ls not allowed on svg element at this point** and **End tag svg did not match the name of the current open element (use).**

here is a sample code i used.

```
<svg class="ls-l" style="top:320px;left:30%;white-space: nowrap;" 
    data-ls="offsetxin:-15; offsetyin:10; delayin:6854; offsetxout:-15; offsetyout:10; durationout:500; showuntil:1000; easingout:easeInOutQuart; scalexin:0; scaleyin:0; scalexout:0; scaleyout:0;" 
    width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 64 64" >
    <use xlink:href="#location-pin">
</svg>
```

Thanks....

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way that makes the answers not make sense any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data- attributes are not strictly valid for svg you can get and set them using getAttribute and setAttribute but the html [data attribute API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) is not available, hence the warning.

The usual XML way would be to declare a custom namespace and then have the attribute in that namespace e.g. have a `xmlns:ls="<something appropriate for you>"` and `ls:<something>="offsetxin..."` and then access the data using `getAttributeNS`

The `<use>` issue is that you don't close the `<use>` tag. You either need to write it as `<use/>` or `<use></use>`

Comment: Hey thanks for quick response.. <use /> this work charm. But can u please give me more info how i can achieve "xmlns:ls="<something appropriate for you>" and myns:ls="offsetxin..."

Comment: Use your imagination and create something unique for yourself "something appropriate for you" and "something"