# How to check SVG file Validation?

Tags: ios, svg

While checking validation of SVG file, it showing error: Attribute data-name not allowed on SVG element pattern at this point.
Not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Add your sample of original svg.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Showing error in this line: <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1216.4 913.5">    ERROR: Attribute data-name not allowed on SVG element svg at this point

Comment: Add svg file pls.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I am not able to attach SVG file here.

Comment: @dahiya_boy How can I add SVG file here? Please comment.

Comment: upload on google drive and share the link for download.

Comment: We need more info. What validator are you using? `data-name` is not a valid SVG1.1 attribute.  But is being added to SVG2 and [most browsers support it already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement/dataset).  I can't tell you why your particaular validator is complaining - especially since you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Link of SVG: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdoApJ606kCXd8tfYqWGjAqs_BTOhY94/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Validator that i am using is: https://validator.w3.org. I use validate by file upload. In that case it gives me 18 errors and error is: Attribute data-name not allowed on SVG element svg at this point. Link of SVG file that i am using is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdoApJ606kCXd8tfYqWGjAqs_BTOhY94/view

Answer (score 1):

The `data-*` attributes were first officially defined in the HTML5 standard as an HTML feature.  The SVG 1.1 standard predates that by around 10 years.  Data attributes have now been added to the SVG2 specification, but that is not yet an official specification.

The W3C SVG validator has not yet been updated to support SVG 2 documents.  When it does, I expect it will not flag data attributes as an error.  Until then, you should either remove the attributes, or ignore the validator errors.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

According to SVG validation markup [guide](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/guide/markup.html#common-attributes)

> For SVG-in-HTML, use HTML-style data attributes; any attribute name that starts with data- is for custom data. Beware: the matching dataset DOM property on the element object is new in SVG 2, and won’t be supported everywhere. **Use `getAttribute()/setAttribute()` for best support**.

i.e. Now `data-`pattern is no more supported. I have checked SVG by removing `data-name` & it is working normally w/o any error.

For the get/set attributes you need javascript help which I dont know but if you tell us why you need this tag may be we try to find some alternative that coukld help you around.

You have one warning ***No Character encoding declared at document level*** , which can be fixed by adding below line at top of your svg file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

---

Hope it helped anyhow.

Comment: As you said "Now data-pattern is no more supported", my SVG file is SVG1.1. data-pattern is not supported in this 1.1. Are you saying this?

Comment: I got [2014 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034699/attribute-data-ls-not-allowed-on-element-svg-at-this-point-how-to-rectify-it) relevant to same issue. Still it was suggested to use get/set. Your SVG is 1.1 and data-pattern expected to be work but its not. Here in [2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6517e186-3ee5-4c97-bd1e-9b1cc6019b50/how-to-solve-quotattribute-xmlnsb-not-allowed-herequot?forum=xmlandnetfx) someone also said data-pattern not working

Comment: [W3C made lots of changes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/). My answer is not exact & exact answer can be explained by the HTML, XML tags SO's.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for the info. It helps me somehow.

Comment: One more thing I want to know, as you said that  "I have checked SVG by removing data-name & it is working normally w/o any error." Then what you right in that place data-name.

Comment: @kritikaperiwal Nothing just remove them. To identify different sectors of SVG use ID instead of data-name.

Comment: First line of SVG file code: <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1216.4 913.5"> I use ID in plcae od data-name and it's like this now <svg id="Layer_1" ID="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1216.4 913.5"> But it is showing me ERROR: Attribute ID not allowed on SVG element svg at this point.

Comment: @kritikaperiwal remove this ->  `data-name="Layer 1"`. By using ID I meant to rectify the sectors. You can only use HTML 5 tags in SVG.

Comment: Thanks. Showing no error to me also. Have you any idea to use Framework like Pocket SVG or SVG kit?

Comment: @kritikaperiwal If this answer helped you then pls accept the answer. I have done SVGKit, if you facing issues in kit then post new question bcz one question with multi different answers will create conflict to the future developers when then see this post.